# Reference request: measure restricted

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, notation

Let $\nu$ denote a finite and signed measure. I am reading some notes in which the notation
$$\nu\big|_{[a, b]}\ge 0$$
is used (here $a, b>0$).

Anyone could please tell me what does it mean?
Clearly this notation is not defined in the notes, but I gather from the context that it could mean that for any function $f$ supported in $[a, b]$, it is
$$\int_{supp(f)} f(x) d\nu(x) = \int_{supp(f)} f(x) d\nu^+(x),$$
with $\nu^+$ denotes the positive part of $\nu$.

Anyone could please provide a reference?

Comment: My best guess is $\nu(A) \geq 0$ for every measurable $A \subseteq [a,b]$, which should be equivalent to what you are suggesting.

Comment: Is $\nu$ a finite signed measure defined on Borel subsets of the real line? What is $\nu^+$?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this means the measure $\eta:\mathcal{B}\to (-\infty,\infty)$, given by $\eta(A)=\nu(A\cap [a,b])$ for all $A\in \mathcal{B}$ measurable.

If you care about what measures you can plug into measure, it could also mean restricting to the natural $\sigma$-sub-algebra $\mathcal{B'}=\{ C\subseteq [a,b]: C=A\cap [a,b],\; A\in \mathcal{B} \}$, and defining the measure as above.

Perhaps [Restriction of a finite measure to a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016914/restriction-of-a-finite-measure-to-a-set-on-unbounded-function) or [Correct notation for restriction of measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336950/correct-notation-for-restriction-of-measure) can help you.

Ultimately it depends on the intention of who wrote the notes, so it could be something different.